# Hard disk access in Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

Today I tried to install Ubuntu alongside windows 8, but Ubuntu overwrote my Windows. I had important data in my F drive. Can I access this data from Ubuntu or by any other method?

Comment: Can you reach the data from Ubuntu? Open file manager (press windows key and type nautilus) and check if your drive is listed in devices on the left.

Answer (score 0):

pull the drive, install into a different system and search the drive and hope for the best. If you are lucky, you will be able to get some of your stuff. The other option, "expensive" is to send it off and have someone pull the first layer of data away and get to your old data. I do not think there are any free or even cheap open source/COTS that will do the job for you.